# Why $e^{iπ}=-1$ and not $e^{180i}=-1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, exponential-function

I know that $e^{iπ}=-1$ is the outcome of the identity $e^{ix}=cos(x)+isin(x)$ when $x=π$. What I don't understand is: why radians? Wouldn't it also be true that $e^{180i}=-1$ - just in different units? And wouldn't the identity $e^{i\pi}=-1$, then, only be true when $-1$ is the number of radians?

Comment: Exponentials function can be defined purely analytically by $\exp(z) = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}$ for any complex $z$, then it happens that $t\mapsto\exp(it)$ winds the unit circle with the unit speed so that this map is an arc-length parametrization. This is where radian enters this business rather than being an arbitrary choice.

Comment: I see; that does kind of make intuitive sense. However, if we use the Taylor Expansion method, we get the sines and the cosines undefined as to what units should be used. Is there any way to explain that?

Comment: The Taylor expansion of sine is $\sin(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i{x}^{2i+1}/(2i+1)!$, not $\sin(x)=\sum_{i=0}^\infty(-1)^i(x\cdot \pi/180)^{2i+1}/(2i+1)!$.

Comment: Of course there is nothing stops you from using other units than radian. They can equally be used in place of radian without changing any theoretical detail. The radian being both economical (as you need not worry about pesky constants popping up everywhere) and natural (in connection with complex exponential and so on), however, I see no good reason to bother to use alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

These two are in different units! The measure of an angle is either expressed in `radians` or degrees. The notations used is $2\pi$ radians is one full round (circle), which is same as $360^\circ$.

Thus $\pi$ radians is **exactly same as** $180^\circ$.

Comment: The fact that they are different units was the exact point of my question. Why do we use radians and not degrees?